# Mirth Add Segment HL7 V3

Tags: mirth

I am new to Mirth/JavaScript. I have a project where I need to add a segment to an incoming HL7 v3 XML file. I have tried the following JavaScript in the destination transformer;

```
tmp = msg.copy();
tmp.createSegment('templateId', ClinicalDocument, 1);
tmp.ClinicalDocument['templateId'][1]['@root'] ="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1";
```

This generates an error.

Also I need to place this new segment before the existing templateID segment.
Currently this is what we receive –

```
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:mif="urn:hl7-org:v3/mif" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc">
<realmCode code="US" />
<typeId root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3" extension="POCD_HD000040" /><br/>
<templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.2" extension="2015-08-01" />
```

We want to add

Tranformed Output Desired -

Any help on how to accomplish this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: It would be helpful to know, what specific error you are getting, when you mention "This generates an error"

Answer (score 0):

I understand your requirement in this way. That you need to add

```
<templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1" extension="2015-08-01" />
```

Exactly before the templateID

```
<templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.2" extension="2015-08-01" />
```

If that's the requirement, this JAVA code will work

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        // Source XML
        File fXmlFile = new File("C:\\Labs\\POC\\Import_Export\\TEST.xml");
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        // Get the element after which template ID code has to be added
        Node nodeName = doc.getElementsByTagName("typeId").item(0);
        // Code to add new Template ID
        Element newTemplateID = doc.createElement("templateId");
        newTemplateID.setAttribute("root", "2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1");
        newTemplateID.setAttribute("extension", "2015-08-01");
        // Inserting exactly on specific area
        nodeName.getParentNode().insertBefore(newTemplateID, nodeName.getNextSibling());


        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        // destination XML
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\Labs\\POC\\Import_Export\\TESTNew.xml"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    }
```

you will get an XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:mif="urn:hl7-org:v3/mif" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc">
<realmCode code="US"/>
<typeId extension="POCD_HD000040" root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3"/>
<templateId extension="2015-08-01" root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1"/>
<templateId extension="2015-08-01" root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.2"/>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

Refactor the above code for Mirth specification u will get same output, else u simply want to add extra tags on the end of xml you can use this code in Mirth script

```
var addTemplateId = new XML("<templateId></templateId>");
addTemplateId['@root'] = '2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1';
addTemplateId['@extension'] = '2015-08-01';
var newValue = msg.appendChild(addTemplateId);

msg = newValue;
```

This will add new tags at the end of the existing tags of the message. which means your output will be like this

```
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:mif="urn:hl7-org:v3/mif" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc">
<realmCode code="US"/>
<typeId extension="POCD_HD000040" root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3"/>
<templateId extension="2015-08-01" root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.2"/>
<templateId extension="2015-08-01" root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.1.1"/>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

Comment: You are not new in Mirth development. Don't you see this is the CCD document with tons of other stuff after template declaration? So what is advice you giving here by adding the tag at the end of all section level templates?

Comment: No Shamil, I have given the Java code to pick up particular tag and then insert data after that. I have also given an additional solution just in case if they want to add tags a the end alone that will work

Comment: The solution might be much simpler but John refuses provide details.